# Accessing Twitter historic data in near-past

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to access historic Twitter data?

I want to write a function that accesses tweets which match certain keywords, like the FilterStream in the Twitter streaming API, but can access tweets which have been created historically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not.

All you can do, is use search method to get recent matching tweets. (little amount if keywords are unpopular)
Or connect to streaming API and wait (in little while you will have historic tweets)